# C function with pointers work on one computer, and doesn't work on another

Tags: c, function, pointers, swap

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap (int *a, int *b)
 {
    int *tmp;
    *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *tmp;
 }

int main ()
{
 int x = 5;
 int y = 7;
 swap (&x,&y);
 printf ("\n x = %d \n y = %d \n",x,y);
}
```

I'm using codeblocks, and this code won't work, and I don't understand why... On one computer it works perfectly but on the other it won't run at all.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*tmp = *a;` dont you get a warning?

Comment: It is not broken, what can be cause of this? Maybe bad sectors on HDD? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No, i was being sarcastic, your program is not working for the reason exposed by **Gopi** you are dereferencing an invalid pointer, which is undefined behavior, it means precisely that it will not behave consistently, hence the behavior is different across computers for example.

Comment: I think Gopi aleady adequately answered your question, but one thing that would save time would be to just make `tmp` an integer, not a pointer.  All you have to do is remove some `*`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was to use uninitialized memory. Always allocate memory to a pointer before using it. Next, don't forget to free the allocated memory after you're done with it.

Also, you should add `return 0;` at the end of your `main()` function.

If you don't mind a second opinion, check the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap (int *a, int *b)
{
        int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
        *tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = *tmp;
        free(tmp);
}

int main ()
{
        int x = 5;
        int y = 7;
        swap (&x,&y);
        printf ("\n x = %d \n y = %d \n",x,y);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pardon me if i'm being rude, but instead of hit-and-run downvote, please take the time to improve the quality of Q&As, like mentioning the requirement of `return 0` [I'm a bit surprised not to see this, even as a _comment_ or _sidenote_].

Comment: c99 standard (5.1.2.2.3) says: `reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.`, so you don't need the `return 0;` at the end of the main function.

Comment: @mch I never said it is an `error` or `problem`. All I mentioned is _quality_. It's good practice. Hope i'm not misunderstood. :-)

Comment: in that case you should write "you should add a `return 0;`..." instead of "you need to..."

Comment: @mch point taken. Now I'm on the way. Can you please do the edit, please?

Answer (score 7):

```
int tmp;
tmp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = tmp;
```

What you need is a variable `tmp` to store the value and not a pointer `*tmp`.

The below code really a poor way of doing this but

```
int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *tmp;
```

Once done please free the memory using

```
free(tmp);
```

Comment: you can explain a bit what is happening, it would increase the correct answer quality.

Comment: It works like this, but I wanted to use pointers ON tmp. I know it works this way, I've done it this way before I tried with pointers.

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић Why do you need to bend your back to get this easy thing done?

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић Check the edits if you really want to do it this way

Comment: @iharob Yes sir took care of it :)

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић - *why* do you want `tmp` to be a pointer?  `*a` and `*b` refer to *integer* objects, so you need a third *integer* object to act as your temporary storage.  There's no reason to use a third pointer in this case.

Comment: @JohnBode like I said, it's for educational purposes, I found out answer to this topic in these answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Gopi already corrected your code - adding on to the previous answer - i think this is good to know information for a newbie:

Section 4.1 states:

> An lvalue (3.10) of a
>   non-function, non-array type T can be
>   converted to an rvalue. If T is an
>   incomplete type, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion is
>   ill-formed. If the object to which the
>   lvalue refers is not an object of type
>   T and is not an object of a type
>   derived from T, or **if the object is
>   uninitialized**, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion **has
>   undefined behavior**. If T is a
>   non-class type, the type of the rvalue
>   is the cv-unqualified version of T.
>   Otherwise, the type of the rvalue is
>   T.

When you try to dereference and uninitialized pointer the behavior is undefined. Undefined means anything can happen - there is no guarantee. So you can get different behavior in different environments.

From Wiki [Making pointers safer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Making_pointers_safer)

> A pointer which does not have any address assigned to it is called a wild pointer. Any attempt to use such uninitialized pointers can cause unexpected behavior, either because the initial value is not a valid address, or because using it may damage other parts of the program. The result is often a segmentation fault, storage violation or wild branch (if used as a function pointer or branch address).

What you did here:

```
int *tmp;
*tmp = *a;
```

is that you created a pointer to int which is not pointing to anything - basically it contains some junk value (could be your pincode even - who knows).

Comment: hes mistake was so basic that this much of information will just confuse him more.

Comment: `was so basic` UB is the most basic mistake which newbies make.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel I agree with al-Acme, it's fairly common to see this mistakes, if someone wants to learn something, they should do it by reading, not by trial and error.

Comment: I created *tmp, in tmp there is some random number, so when write *tmp = *a in that adress(of that random number) it put value of whatever a points to. I'm I wrong? I'm sorry, I am afterall newbie.

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић , `tmp` is a pointer. Where do you think it points to? Some random location! Allocate memory for it using `malloc` as mentioned in Gopi's answer

Comment: `*tmp = *a` means store the value which is in address `a` into the address pointed by `tmp`. Since you did not initialize it - could not `tmp` contain a value like (assuming) `-3424727` or anything in the world? What if try to reach an address in memory which does not exists?

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић you are wrong, `tmp` points to an invalid place, if you dereference it you invoke `Undefined Behavior` and since the behavior is not defined you might get a random number, you might get `segmentation fault` it's undefined.

Comment: @iharob I did not disagree with what he said, just the way he posted it. The edit he made to the answer should be the first thing, and than later he could insert reference, not the opposite.

Comment: So basically here is problem that *tmp points to some adress that does not exist? And if I want to use pointers like I did I need to somehow initialize tmp? So that *tmp points to something that exists?

Comment: `*tmp points to some adress that does not exist?` - It is possible or **can point to some valid address** as well. There is **no guarantee**. `And if I want to use pointers like I did I need to somehow initialize tmp? So that *tmp points to something that exists?` Yes.

Comment: How you initialized the pointer, that's another thing. You can use `malloc` you can make it point to the address of a variable in the stack, you can create an array and it will automatically behave as a pointer when used as one ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27924154/1983495)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointers, although it does not make any sense at all

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp[1];

    *tmp = *a;
    *a   = *b;
    *b   = *tmp;
}
```

here `tmp` is not strictly a pointer, but you can use the `*` indirection operator on it.

Or

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int value = *a;
    int *tmp  = &value;

    *tmp = *a;
    *a   = *b;
    *b   = *tmp;
}
```

Or you can use `malloc` as **Gopi** already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointers, then do use pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int ** ppx, int ** ppy)
 {
   int * p = *ppx;
   *ppx = *ppy;
   *ppy = p;
 }

int main (void)
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 7;
  int * px = &x;
  int * py = &y;

  printf ("\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", *px, *py);

  swap (&px, &py);

  printf ("\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", *px, *py);

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
x = 5
y = 7

x = 7
y = 5
```